# Animate wrappanel items repositioning

Tags: wpf, animation, zooming, wrappanel, wii

I'm trying to create an animation like the text zoom animation that exists in the wii news channel. See [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uO6J8ryTKYk&noredirect=1) at 0:45 to an example.

My current code is to take a string, split it into a string[] between the spaces, create a textblock for each word, and inserting it into a List of TextBlocks.

After that, I need to put it as an ItemsSource of a WrapPannel, and change the fontsize of each textblock to generate the zoom effect. This will make the correct positioning, but without any animation.

I also searched about FluidMoveBehavior, but I don't know how to apply this to my situation.

How can I animate the repositioning of the items into the wrap panel? My approach is the best way to do that?

Comment: I think I've seen something similar in the [WPF Bag of Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot). You might want to check it out. It includes full samples of everything.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks, I'll check